# не получается выводить программу через sublime text на cmd

Tags: python, sublime-text

извините если это тупой вопрос,просто я только сегодня начал изучать пайтон и тут же проблема
Когда я пытаюсь запустить код через enter или f5 ничего не происходит,просто строка переносится.в cmd перед кодом написал все как должно быть то естьь флажок с пайтоном и тд.Но код никак не реагирует,просто переносит строку.Буду благодарен если кто ниубль напишет что нужно делать

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что вообще не понятно, кто куда и какие строки переносит.